# How to change current table row as highlighted if any modification done in that row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

how to make current table row as highlighted if I change any input text or image of that particular table row using Jquery. As code given below which contains two rows, so out of which how to make any of the row as highlighted if I modify input text or change image by keypress event or any other solutions please let me know

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="browse-chg-img">
          <img style="width: 100px; height: 75px;" src="../fileuploads/BulkImgUpload/abc.jpg" />
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text" style="font-size: 10px;">Change Image</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="browse-chg-img">
          <img style="width: 100px; height: 75px;" src="../fileuploads/BulkImgUpload/abc.jpg" />
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text" style="font-size: 10px;">Change Image</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: add code attempted by you here or better create a fiddle!

Comment: the above part of the code only I have tried. Just I want particular row should be heiglighted (or background color change) if any modification for that row

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td').on('keydown', function(ev) {
    $('tr').css('background-color','');
    $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color','red');        
  });
});
```

jsFiddle for the same

https://jsfiddle.net/0k8Lu50v/

Comment: Is this helpful to you?  @Shivanand L.C

Comment: Glad it helps :) If you find it's useful to you please marked as answer for future references as well

Answer (score 0):

Try giving styles to tr,

```
<style>
    tr:focus { background: yellow; }
    </style>
    <table>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>1</td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ></td>
                                                    <td><textarea class="form-control"></textarea></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="browse-chg-img">
                                                            <img style="width: 100px; height: 75px;" src="../fileuploads/BulkImgUpload/abc.jpg" />
                                                            <div class="overlay">
                                                                <div class="text" style="font-size: 10px;">Change Image</div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>                                                    
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>2</td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ></td>
                                                    <td><textarea class="form-control"></textarea></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="browse-chg-img">
                                                            <img style="width: 100px; height: 75px;" src="../fileuploads/BulkImgUpload/abc.jpg" />
                                                            <div class="overlay">
                                                                <div class="text" style="font-size: 10px;">Change Image</div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>                                                    
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
```